# Gcm vs other push service

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have problem with GCM, sometimes have delay with android and ios app.
Is there any other solution which doesn't have that delay?

What about parse push?

Answer (score 1):

Given that parse push is just an layer on top of GCM, I don't see how they would be any better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list you can use:

- [Parse.com](https://parseplatform.org/)
- [Grokking Android](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/)
- [PushOver](https://pushover.net/)
- [Mixpanel](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/android-push-notifications)
- [App42 Client](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Push-Notification-Android/)